# Multiplayer bonus for getting Ishak Pasha's armour?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I've just completed the Hagia Sophia challenge level and, as well as Ishak Pasha's armor, got the message `Multiplayer bonus unlocked`.

This happened once before - after assassinating a particular character, this message appeared and apparently this corresponded to me unlocking that character as a multiplayer character.

I don't have Xbox Live Gold - I can't go into the multiplayer menus at all, so I can't have a look for myself. I've looked at lists of multiplayer characters on the internet and can't find one that either (a) looks like it relates to Ishak Pasha or (b) specifically says it's unlocked like this.

So, what did I just unlock?

Comment: These "bonuses" are nothing to get worked up about, you just get templar profile items which doesn't really give you much in multiplayer.  I don't remember which items correspond to the bonuses you are referring to but it's not a big deal really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character you assasinated and unlocked was [Shahkulu](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Shahkulu), killing him unlocks the [Renegade](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Renegade) MP character. He's really easy to spot in the crown and has a distinctive fast-walk animation, making him a really bad choice.

Completing the Hagia Sophia dungeon unlocks an icon shown for your 'templar profile' during MP sessions. It looks like Jack Black with a moustache.

The MP icons are kinda pointless - really it should show your gamer tag icon instead, but I guess it's yet another collectible for you to keep playing for.

Comment: Yeah, I found that character for the assassination unlock, so I imagined that the armor unlock would be another character, but I couldn't find it. Now I know why :)